# Paired studies: possible drawbacks

Tags: experiment-design, biostatistics, matching, medicine

I have a question regarding paired studies. We are doing a medical study, we have a whole lot of data on a few hundred people and our aim is to study if a different level in one substance is linked to a different version of a disease. The general practice in the field seems to be to pair the subjects and then analyse the data - one type of the disease (Type A) is more prevalent among younger population than the other (Type B).

We have not really found any difference in the substance levels in the paired analysis, we paired the subjects by age and there is a theory that there is actually only one kind of the disease, that Type A transforms into Type B as the subjects age (or sometimes they already acquire Type B, mostly if they are older).

My question is: Is it valid to pair the subjects like this? Especially since we pair them by age, which seems to be an important factor? What are the possible drawbacks of such pairings, what is crucial not to neglect?

Please could you point me to some literature which deals with these statistical questions - to me it seems that there might be something wrong with the approach, but I can't put a finger on it.

Comment: It seems you try to do match maybe this can help https://wiki.ecdc.europa.eu/fem/w/wiki/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-matching.aspx